# Android phone not connecting to webservice but emulator is connecting- timeout error

Tags: android, web-services

New to Android, I have .Net webservices residing in my PC. when my Android application calls the webservice from emulator with below code (where XX.XX.XX.XX is my IP address), it runs perfectly.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 1000000); //Timeout Limit
                        HttpResponse response;
                    try {
                        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://XX.XX.XX.XX/SDService_SAFTI/ServiceSD.svc/LoginUser");
```

But running the same code in mobile does not work. Error as below. Can it be a port issue? Both phone and PC are on the same network. Any suggestions are welcome. Many thanks in advance.

```
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /XX.XX.XX.XX:80 timed out
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:163)
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:597)
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:517)
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:495)
03-03 08:55:37.350 3273-4019/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at com.androidatc.customviewindrawer.LoginFrag$1.run(LoginFrag.java:121)
```

After running for some time, now its showing below logcat.

```
03-03 09:05:56.793 12466-12685/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/System.out: [CDS]connect[/192.168.0.102:80] tm:1000
03-03 09:08:09.392 12466-12517/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/ViewRootImpl: ANR Key Analyze: No Key event currently.
03-03 09:08:09.394 12466-12517/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/ViewRootImpl: ANR Key Analyze: Previeous Event null,finish at 2016-03-03 09:05:56.094
03-03 09:08:09.394 12466-12517/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/ViewRootImpl: ANR Motion Analyze: No motion event currently.
03-03 09:08:09.395 12466-12517/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/ViewRootImpl: ANR Motion Analyze: Previeous Event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=609.4357, y[0]=967.4961, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=243593704, downTime=243593647, deviceId=6, source=0x1002 },finish at 2016-03-03 09:05:56.778
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.b(SourceFile:77)
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.c(SourceFile:75)
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$a.get(SourceFile:97)
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(SourceFile:35)
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:59)
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder:     at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1232)
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder:     at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:679)
03-03 09:08:09.404 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/Binder:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
03-03 09:08:09.405 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
03-03 09:08:09.405 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.b(SourceFile:77)
03-03 09:08:09.405 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.c(SourceFile:75)
03-03 09:08:09.405 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$a.get(SourceFile:97)
03-03 09:08:09.405 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(SourceFile:35)
03-03 09:08:09.405 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:59)
03-03 09:08:09.405 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1232)
03-03 09:08:09.405 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:679)
03-03 09:08:09.405 12466-12488/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
03-03 09:08:09.453 12466-12480/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/art: Thread[9,tid=12480,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x55a71953d0,peer=0x12c53080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
03-03 09:08:09.661 12466-12480/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

[image]

Updated - screenshot - port forwarding:

[image]

Comment: Is your phone and pc on the same network?

Comment: Yes, both are on the same network.

Comment: Can you try pulling the /data/anr/traces.txt file out of your device?

Comment: Ok, let me find out - how to pull that.

Comment: `adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt` is the command.

Comment: Thanks, but where can I run this command? I saw a some articles where where to run is not mentioned. My PC command prompt says - unrecognized command.

Comment: I had Android studio, but installed Android Sdk again: C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\tools but it says that adb file has moved to platform-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do this is by using port forwarding:

1) Connect your device and open chrome on both your mobile and laptop browser.

2) On the URL tab, type chrome://inspect

3) Click on port forwarding and add a new row, with port as 8888 and IP as webservice_url:port.
[image]

4) Now in your android application code, replace webservice_url:port with localhost:8888.
Basically now on 8888 your mobile will call the computer webservice url. Note: Make sure that chrome is open on both your laptop and the device. And when you type chrome://inspect you should be able to see the device you have attached.

Refer to this for more help: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your Androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Tried that, pls see the screen attached (updated question). chrome://inspect/#devices is not available
chrome://inspect/#devices
inspectfocus tabreloadclose

Comment: you dont need to put chrome://inspect on the mobile url tab. The phone is showing and thats good. You can start with step 3 now. Just add the port forwarding part as in the answer above and then on your mobile try accessing the weservice url. Do let me know if you still face issues.

Comment: Sid, pls see the screenshot which I updated in the question. I think its not allowing port forwarding? I also tried after this and no luck with web services working.

Comment: I did see the screenshot. You port forwarding button seems to be active on the laptop. Just click on that. Then as in my answer write 8888 in the first column and the <webservice-url:port > in the second column and click on done. You dont need to do port forwarding on the mobile side. Now go to your mobile and just type the <webservice-url:port > in chrome.

Comment: Still same after port forwarding (step 3). Logcat - 3-04 07:43:45.545 13011-13276/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/System.out: [socket][0] connection /192.168.0.102:80;LocalPort=51174(100000000)
03-04 07:43:45.546 13011-13276/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/System.out: [CDS]connect[/192.168.0.102:80] tm:100000

Comment: on the mobile browser URL type: localhost:8888 and let me know what happens

Comment: After step 4 - Logcat --> 
03-04 07:48:42.022 17100-17314/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/System.out: [CDS]connect[/192.168.0.102:8888] tm:100000
03-04 07:48:42.058 17100-17314/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/System.out: [socket][1:58941] exception
03-04 07:48:42.058 17100-17314/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer I/System.out: [CDS]close[58941]
03-04 07:48:42.058 17100-17314/com.androidatc.customviewindrawer W/System.err: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.0.102:8888 refused

Comment: on the mobile browser URL type: localhost:8888 --> it says no data received.

Comment: one last try, just show me a snapshot of the chrome port forwarding page, where you have added the new url.

Comment: Updated the question with the screenshot ( Updated - screenshot - port forwarding:)

Comment: then how are you hitting the webservice? ideally wherever you are hitting the webservice should now be replaced with localhost:8888

Comment: I meant - not explicitly mentioned that in the code (only IP address).

Comment: then try adding the port, wherever you are giving the URL replace it with localhost:8888, after doing all the steps mentioned above

Comment: It is working now. Many thanks!! Appreciate you help Sid.